# django template tag not getting invoked more than once in javascript function

Tags: javascript, django, django-template-filters

In my django application, I have created a template tag function that generates a random number that I am assigning as random IDs to programmatically generated  elements.

```
 import os
 import random
 from django import template

 register = template.Library()

 @register.tag(name="randomgen")
 def randomgen(parser, token):
     items = []
     bits = token.split_contents()
     for item in bits:
         items.append(item)
     return RandomgenNode(items[1:])

 class RandomgenNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, items):
       self.items = []
       for item in items:
          self.items.append(item)

    def render(self, context):
        arg1 = self.items[0]
        arg2 = self.items[1]
        if "hash" in self.items:
            result = os.urandom(16).encode('hex')
        elif "float" in self.items:
            result = random.uniform(int(arg1), int(arg2))
        elif not self.items:
            result = random.random()
        else:
            result = random.randint(int(arg1), int(arg2))
        return result
```

In my html template, I have used the load tag to import the template tag .py file:

```
{% load custom_tag %}
```

On a particular button click, the randomgen() function is invoked only once:

```
$(document).on("click", ".add_div_btn", function() {
     let random_id = "{% randomgen 100 1000 %}";
     <!-- will generate a random number between 10 and 100 -->
     console.log("random id: ", random_id);
});
```

However, every button click after the first one generates the same number.

On checking the console log, i found out that the randomgen() function within the custom_tag.py file was getting called only once.

I am unsure how to make a proper invocation call to the django template tag function in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is run in the frontend and Django template tags are run on the server.

The JavaScript in your template ends up being rendered as (e.g.)

```
$(document).on("click", ".add_div_btn", function() {
     let random_id = "477";
     <!-- will generate a random number between 10 and 100 -->
     console.log("random id: ", random_id);
});
```

so of course it will always print the same ID.

If you really, *really* need to generate the random ID server-side, you would need to do an AJAX/fetch call to an API endpoint on the server... but what you really probably want is

```
$(document).on("click", ".add_div_btn", function() {
     let random_id = Math.floor(100 + Math.random() * (1000 - 100));
     // will generate a random number between 10 and 1000
     console.log("random id: ", random_id);
});
```

and no custom template tag at all.

Comment: that is actually a good idea, using a basic random number generator function of javascript instead.

Comment: Since you mentioned ajax calls, could you give an example of making an ajax call to a django template tag function?

Comment: That's really out of the scope of this question, but any old example of `fetch()` and a simple view returning a JSON response would do.